# Is there a way where we can observe both electric field lines and magnetic field lines at the same time around something?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

As we already acknowledge, we can see magnetic field lines by putting compasses or iron filings around a current-carrying wire. Same goes to electric field lines where we can see them when we are looking at plasma balls/plasma globes and what these clips show https://youtu.be/zz9l8e4Rq00?t=48 and https://youtu.be/7vnmL853784?t=168.

I wonder if it is possible to see both electric field lines and magnetic field lines around a wire or anything at the same time, or will one of them dominate the other so that only a single field (either the electric field lines or magnetic field lines) will be observed? What will it looks like?

Comment: EM waves are typically a condition where both fields are important. Depending on the geometry of the source, the field lines can be more or less complicated.

Comment: Guess : you could use this method to find electric field lines,  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oD9amPhBi8k&t=47s , and put ut two magnets as the conductors , then  try the iron files.

Comment: @LPZ so we can make how we want the EM field lines look like according to our own likings depending on for example the antenna designs.

Comment: @annav how to make those two magnets as conductors?

Comment: magnets are made of metal so they **are** conductors.

Comment: @annav sorry I actually meant to ask how to use the two magnets as conductors, is it by just putting them inside the container?

Comment: I guess so, in the place of the two pins. The the electric field should be detected the same as in the video, and I would try a plastic tray with with iron filings over the container to see the magnetic lines.

Comment: @annav because none of the experiment materials are available right now, I just try to draw the hypothetical magnetic field lines by using individual charges. Do you think the magnetic field lines will look like this https://i.imgur.com/27wKZxX.png? Look at the circular magnetic field lines near both the pins

Comment: No. look at this https://www.toppr.com/ask/content/concept/properties-of-magnetic-field-lines-around-a-bar-magnet-209676/ , the heads in place of pins  should be the pole of the magnet and the iron filings would open around the poles, if opposite, north south the lines should go from one to the other, if the same there should be the repulsion lines.

Comment: @annav Let me see if I understand you correctly. When you said "the heads in place of pins should be the pole of the magnet" do you mean something like in this picture https://i.imgur.com/h8ud8bQ.png ? If we make the magnets as conductors, will the electric field affect the magnetic field lines?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145724/discussion-between-snoopykid-and-anna-v).